# When does the loadoperation completed event fire?

Tags: c#, events

Class `DomainContext` has method Invoke which return instance of `InvokeOperation`
and often we can see next   code

```
InvokeOperation op = domainConextInstance.Invoke(...);
op.Completed +={...};
```

My first thought - it should not work: after all event can arise earlier than we will subscribe for it.

I  made an experiment

```
InvokeOperation op = domainConextInstance.Invoke(...);
Thread.Sleep(5000); //or 25000
op.Completed +={...};
```

But I found that this code works correctly, But how? 
Can you explain this to me?

And what pattern does this construct use?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without seeing any of the code for `DomainContext` - but it sounds like the code which adds a handler for the `Completed` event calls the handler immediately if the operation has already completed.

Assuming you have the code for `InvokeOperation`, I'd definitely look at the declaration of the `Completed` event to discover the "magic".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are talking about WCF RIA Services SDK, Jon is right. InvokeOperation has a property `IsComplete`. The `add` part of the Completed event checks this property. In case of a completed operation it does not add the passed event handler but calls it immediately.

You can validate this by inspecting OperationBase (base class of InvokeOperation) in System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll with a disassemler tool like dotPeek.